# Why do I need to use `&` to trigger deref coercion in rust?

Tags: rust, reference, coercion

From **The Rust Programming Language** book:

> Deref coercion converts a reference to a type that implements the
> `Deref` trait into reference to another type

Questions in code snippet below:

- Why `&` is required for `deref` to be implicitly called, isn't  `m` already a reference?
- `hello(m.deref().deref())` works without & operator `MyBox<String> -> String -> &str` convert is happening underneath:

  - if I add `&` in front of convert sequence - that would be `&MyBox<String> -> &String -> &&str`, why `&&` is folded in final case (e.g. `&&str -> &str` when `hello(&m)` is called)?
- Why I cannot use `hello(m)` instead, without `&` for passing `m`?

```
use std::ops::Deref;

struct MyBox<T>(T);

impl<T> MyBox<T> {
    fn new(x: T) -> MyBox<T> {
        MyBox(x)
    }
}

impl<T> Deref for MyBox<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn hello(name: &str) {
    println!("Hello, {name}!");
}

fn main() {
    let m = MyBox::new(String::from("Rust"));

    // Why `&` is required for deref to be implicitly called, 
    // isn't  m already a reference?
    hello(&m);

    // code below works without & operator 
    // MyBox<String> -> String -> &str convert is happening here
    hello(m.deref().deref());

    // why I cannot use the code like one below, 
    // without & for passing m?, e.g. 
    // hello(m);
}
```

Explanation by compiler for `hello(m)`:

```
   Compiling 
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/bin/tmp3.rs:38:11
   |
38 |     hello(m);
   |     ----- ^ expected `&str`, found `MyBox<String>`
   |     |
   |     arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected reference `&str`
                 found struct `MyBox<String>`
note: function defined here
  --> src/bin/tmp3.rs:19:4
   |
19 | fn hello(name: &str) {
   |    ^^^^^ ----------
help: consider borrowing here
   |
38 |     hello(&m);
   |           +

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `luhn` (bin "tmp3") due to previous error
```

Isn't `m` already borrowed when passed in `hello(m)`?

Answer (score 4):

You've got the first chain types wrong it's not `MyBox<String>` -> `String` -> `&str` but `MyBox<String>` -> `&String` -> `&str`, that works because calling a method automatically inserts the necesary reference.

But from the [list of coercion types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types) you can see only:

> - `&T` or `&mut T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`

is supported, `T` to `&U` where `T` implements `Deref<U>` or `T` to `&T` are simply not amongst the valid coercion types.

So in conclusion the compiler never coerces an owned value to a reference, but coercion from references to other ones is done automatically when the right traits are implemented.

The only time the compiler will insert borrows is when using the method syntax on the `self` parameter, anywhere else only coercion can happen.